# How to auto indent multiple files?

Tags: html, auto-indent

Currently, I generate static files and those files aren't indented properly. Emacs' auto indent works great with `c-x h tab`, but that's per file. I want to auto indent multiple files (Like 50 or so, thus it's not feasible to do it manually).

Is there any way to accomplish this? Whether it be using a different text editor or a script or etc. If it helps, most of the files are `.html`.

Comment: What other tools that you can get? I'm using IntelliJ, where you can easily indent your code easily. Go to "Code -> Reformat Code" will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code below with some HTML files, it works well.

```
(defun indent-file (file-name)
  (save-window-excursion
    (find-file file-name)
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (write-region nil nil file-name)))

;; argv is a list stores command line option. In this case, it will be ("/your/directory/path").
;; directory-files-recursively will find files recursively, and it needs emacs 25.1 or later.
(let* ((target-dir (car argv))
       (target-file-names  (directory-files-recursively target-dir ".*.html$")))
  (dolist (file-name target-file-names)
    (indent-file file-name)))
```

1. Save the code above as 'indent-files.el'
2. Run `emacs --script indent-files.el "/your/directory/path"` in terminal

It will be tricky if you want to use emacs lisp as a common script language, although it actually could indeed. Here are some tips: https://swsnr.de/blog/2014/08/12/emacs-script-pitfalls/

Comment: This works, but is there any way for it to search recursively in the target directory? Also, is it possible to run this from command line (not that I mind too much if I have to open emacs and evaluate the buffer, but just for ease).